# Hoop Hype - A Basketball Puzzle

Tags: sports

There are four basketball games tonight. Three sports writers predict winners in the morning paper.

Bobby BouncePass picks: Clippers, Bulls, Warriors, and Cavs

Donnie Dunks picks: Spurs, Thunder, Warriors, and Clippers

Reggie Rebound picks: Hawks, Bulls, Thunder, and Clippers

no one picks the Knicks.

**Who played whom?**
(a chart may be helpful)

Comment: I would hold off from awarding the tick for a few days in future puzzle. You'll get a bit more attention to the puzzle that way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table (from @Meerkat):

> [image: Answer]

My original logic (not as readable):

> 1) Clippers v Knicks - all of the reporters picked the Clippers, none picked the Kicks.
> 2) Warriors v Hawks - Bobby and Donnie picked the Warriors, Reggie didn't.  So the Warriors played the Hawks, Bulls (picked by Bobby), or Thunder (picked by Donnie). Can only be the Hawks.
> 3) Spurs v Bulls - Bobby and Reggie picked the Bulls.  So the Bulls played either the Spurs or the Thunder (Reggie picked the Thunder).  So it's the Spurs.
> 4) Cavs v Thunder - process of elimination

Comment: [Here's the reasoning in table form.](https://i.imgur.com/zYvUGKa.png) A bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

So Everyone pick's the Clippers, so we don't know who they play, it also means we can eliminate them from the rest of our logic moving forward.

Bobby Picks Bulls, Warriors, Cavs, and Donnie Picks Spurs, Thunder, Warriors. This tells us the Warriors played some yet unnamed team. Also the Bulls/Cavs, played Spurs/Thunder.

Since Reggie Picks Hawks, Bulls, Thunder We now have the missing team that played the Warriors, and know the Bulls did NOT play the Thunder. So Bulls had to play the Spurs, and Cavs had to play the Thunder.

So Clippers played and Unknown Team, that could be assumed was the Knicks, but the riddle didn't specify that the Knicks were playing, only that no one picked them. No one would have picked any other team that was not playing either.
Bulls played the Spurs
Warriors played the Hawks
Cavs Played the Thunder.

> [image: Chart of Picks]

Comment: Hi Richard, welcome to Puzzling.  You should hide your answers using ">!" so that other users can try to solve the puzzle for without clues

Answer (score 1):

> The following table reflects one possibility which satisfies all 3 predictions.
>  The idea is that no prediction should include both teams from the same match.
>  [image]

Answer (score 0):

clippers: BB DD RR, Bulls: BB RR, 
Warriors: BB DD, 
Cavs: BB, 
Spurs: DD, 
Thunder: DD RR, 
Hawks: RR, 
Knicks: nobody.

> If everyone picked the clippers and nobody picked the knicks then they must have played eachother. if BB and RR picked the Bulls and DD is the only one who picked the spurs then they must have faced eachother, apply similar logic to all the other teams and voila you have the answer:Clippers V Knicks, Bulls V Spurs, Warriors V Hawks, Thunder V Cavs.